# Django auto incrementing field that depends on another field

Tags: django-models

I have a model named Hobbies that has the hobbies for certain participants (this is a ForeignKey relationship). For each certain participant I wish to have an auto incrementing field named priority that shows which hobby is prioritized. For example: participant 1 has 3 hobbies with priorities going from 1 to 3, participant 2 has 5 hobbies with priorities going from 1 to 5. Is there a way to have an auto incrementing field that depends on the participant, without making another table in my database?

This is the class for Hobbies:

```
class Hobbies(models.Model):
hobby = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Add hobby', help_text=_('Vul hier 1 van je hobbies in.'))
priority = models.IntegerField()
participant = models.ForeignKey(Deelnemer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['priority']
    verbose_name_plural = 'Hobbies'

def __str__(self):
    return self.hobby
```

If you need more information, I'll add it.

Comment: I don't think that there is a direct way to do that. You can overwrite the save() method to check the last participant's hobby priority and add +1 to it(or assign 1 if this is the first hobby). But what if for some reason you need to change the priority?

Another way to do allow the participant to choose priority number and on save - check the participant's hobbies and auto arrange them. For example hobbies with priorities:

[7, 21, 11, 45, 6] 

would be reevaluated to:

[2, 4, 3, 5, 1]

If there are hobbies with equal priorities the latest one would have advantage.

Comment: thanks a lot I'll try this method